# Keep .click() function after partial data update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a table for a coordinate system, and with a function in each td element to update the field value.

```
[ ][ ][X][ ]
[ ][X][X][X]
[X][ ][ ][ ]
```

When I click an empty element, I want it to set the value to "X" in my database, by getting new partial data from my rails app (and sending GET-variables along), and then re-render the table. This works just fine using my rails app, however ONLY once. It seems like the jQuery function .click() only runs once. The function looks as following: (*generated via. coffeescript*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".field").click(function(e) {
    $.get("http://localhost/dinners?ap="+$(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
      $("#dinner_table").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

This will run just fine, and once I click an element, it will render new data in the table - but only once! If I redefine the .click() function after I swap the HTML in the function, it allows me to click (and update) twice, etc.

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question, but no luck with the searches so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Delegate the event**. By doing this you need attach the handler only once.

```
$(".field").click(function(e) {
```

Will become:

```
$("body").on('click', '.field', function(e) {
```

`body` can be replaced with any static parent container.

Comment: Never heard of this before, but it is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @AllanNørgaard .. Glad to have helped.. For more info on it you can check out this   http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 5):

Use event delegation:

```
$( '#dinner_table' ).on( 'click', '.field', function () {
    /* your click handler */
});
```

So, the click-handler is bound on the common ancestor (the TABLE element, in this case).